# Using default animation in a theme

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-animation

How do I access some of the built in animations like `FadeIn` or `FadeOut` for activities when writing a theme in `Styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Splash_mid</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation"> ??? </item>
  <item name="android:windowExitAnimaiton"> ??? </item>
</style>
```

Basically, I want my **splash screen** to fade out and my **main menu** to fade in.

EDIT:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
        OverridePendingTransition(Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft,
                Android.Resource.Animation.SlideOutRight);
    }
}
```

MenuActivity just pops up instantly instead of animating

EDIT 2:

```
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  package="map_split.map_split"
  android:versionCode="1" 
  android:versionName="1.0" 
  android:installLocation="auto"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" > (...user permissions...) </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default **fade_in** and **fade_out** animation provided by the Android SDK like so:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_mid</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DefaultAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

**These files look like that:**

**fade_in:**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_quad"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**fade_out:**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@interpolator/accelerate_quad" 
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments:

```
OverridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: For some reason implementing this gives me this error: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '@drawable/Splash_mid').`

Comment: Oh yes, but that's another problem. You need to begin naming your files with lowercase letters. I have edited my question to fix that. Make sure to rename your file if it already begins with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Now my splash screen does SlideInLeft (or FadeIn), but doesn't SlideOutRight even though after making an intent in the `OnCreate` of SplashActivity I put `OverridePendingTransition(Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft, Android.Resource.Animation.SlideOutRight);`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for, but SlideInLeft and SlideOutRight are different from FadeIn and FadeOut. What you use now are the fade animations. Others will animate differently.

Comment: Can you post your AppManifest?

Comment: That looks weird. I have tested it on Android Studio, and it worked perfectly without writing any code in the activity. I haven't tried Xamarin before, but maybe you can try my edit in my answer. I haven't tested it though.